# Scope value in Auth.signIn is different from Scope value define in App client of AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for authentication in the Next.js application. Here is the configuration of AWS Cognito in next.js

```
import { Auth, Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
 
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignId: false,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    oauth: {
      domain: config.cognito.DOMAIN,
      scope: ["email", "openid"],
      redirectSignIn: "http://localhost:3000/",
      redirectSignOut: "http://localhost:3000/",
      responseType: "code",
    },
  },
});
```

This function calls on submit button:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
    console.log("user", user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error signing in", error);
  }
});
```

The **OpenID Connect scopes** which defined in AWS Cognito are "**OpenID**", "**Email**" in image below:

[image]

But, the scope value in next.js after calling Auth.signIn is:

```
CognitoUser{ 
 signInUserSession{
  accessToken{
   payload{
    scope: "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
   },
  },
 }
}
```

which is totally different from **AWS Cognito OpenID Connect scopes** values.

Kindly guide me how could I get the same scope values in **Auth.signIn** response which is defined in **AWS Cognito**. Thanks for your help.